# VBA code to reference ranges from closed sheets taking path\file\range from a list of cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to import a range from over 100 excel 2007 workbooks which are saved in different folders to check for changes. I have a list of the path and file names (each on a separate line from 2 to 120):-

```
c:\folderA\folderb\file001.xls
f:\foldera\folder3\fileaaa.xls
d:\folderexample\foldereg\folder12\filea01.xls
```

and so on for over a hundred lines. The range to be imported is always named 'targetrange'. The target files will always be closed. I need to import the target data (1 row x 8 columns) in the eight cells alongside the address.

I have been unable to get this to work successfully.

Subroutine:

```
 Dim PATH, FILENAME, SHEETNAME, CELL, i 
 PATH = "C:\folderA\folderb\file001.xls"
 FILENAME = "Book001.xlsm"
 SHEETNAME = "Sheet1"
 Range = "targetrange"
 For i = 1 To 10
 Range("B" & i) = RETRIEVE(PATH, FILENAME, SHEETNAME, "A" & i)
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Retrieve Function:

```
Function RETRIEVE(PATH, FILENAME, SHEETNAME, CELL)
    RETRIEVE = "='" & PATH & "[" & FILENAME & "]" & SHEETNAME & "'!" & CELL & ""
End Function
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: I have added this code to your question - what is `RetrievePath`?

Comment: Hi retrievepath was a method used to perform the data reference as a function\
        Function RETRIEVE(PATH, FILENAME, SHEETNAME, CELL)        RETRIEVE = "='" & PATH & "[" & FILENAME & "]" & SHEETNAME & "'!" & CELL & ""
End Function      It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want a hard formula reference for each sheet, the following code works well enough. However, YMMV as this will open each workbook and copy the `targetrange` in each to the source workbook.

```
Private Sub RetrieveData()

    Dim SourceSht As Worksheet, TargetWbk As Workbook
    Dim TargetSht As Worksheet
    Dim TargetPath As String, TargetRange As Range

    Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ModifyMe") '--Modify as necessary.

    For i = 1 To 10 '--Modify as necessary.

        '--Set the path.
        TargetPath = SourceSht.Range("B" & i).Value

        '--Turn off everything that can slow/hinder the transfer.
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With

        '--Open the target workbook and qualify all variables.
        Set TargetWbk = Workbooks.Open(TargetPath)
        Set TargetSht = TargetWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set TargetRange = TargetSht.Range("targetrange")

        '--Simple copy and paste.
        TargetRange.Copy SourceSht.Range("C" & i)

        '--Close the target workbook.
        TargetWbk.Close

        '--Turn off everything that can slow/hinder the transfer.
        With Application
            .CutCopyMode = False
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
            .EnableEvents = True
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Let us know if this works. Please try on a duplicate of your workbook.